# Javascript 2D array function

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array, which contains either `true` or `false`.
I made a function that returns the number of neighbors (in all 8 directions) in that array, which are `true`.
But for some unknown reason, it does not work corectly (returns wrong number of neighbors).
(Yes, I'm making Conway's Game of Life.)

```
function neighbors(seq, x, y) {
   var cnt = 0;
   try {
    if (seq[y-1][x]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y][x-1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y][x+1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y+1][x]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y-1][x+1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y-1][x-1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y+1][x-1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }
   try {
    if (seq[y+1][x+1]){
        cnt++;
    }
   }
   catch(err) {

   }        
   return cnt;
}
```

This code was basically translated from my Python code, that works.

Comment: what is the value of `seq`? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Please avoid all this `try..catch`

Comment: @Michael What if i get out of index?

Comment: Replace `try...catch` with normal execution flow `seq[y-1] && seq[y-1][x+1]`. Js doesn't throw when array index is out of bound.

Comment: Just add `if` before to check if you are not on the edge: `if(y > 0)` or `if(x > 0)` where needed. Also, I don't understand why you check only 8 directions and not 9 (disclaimer: I don't know the game..)

Comment: copy pasted your code into js console and it works.

Comment: Which one is the ninth direction?

Comment: LOL my fault ><

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object with all needed directions for counting.

Then check if the index is a key of the array and check the nested level. Add all and return that value.

```
function neighbors(seq, i, j) {
    var directions = [{ x: 0, y: -1 }, { x: -1, y: -1 }, { x: -1, y: 0 }, { x: -1, y: 1 }, { x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: -1 }];

    return directions.reduce((r, { x, y }) => {
            x += i;
            y += j;
            return r + (x in seq && seq[x][y] || 0);
        }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify function like below.

```js
var seq = [[false,false,false,false],
           [false,true,false,false],
           [false,true,false,false],
           [false,true,false,false]]
function neighbors(seq, x, y) {
   var cnt = 0;
   var controls = [{x:0,y:1},{x:0,y:-1},
                    {x:1,y:0},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:-1},
                    {x:-1,y:0},{x:-1,y:1},{x:-1,y:-1}]
   for (var index in controls) {
      var newX = x+controls[index].x;
      var newY = y+controls[index].y;
      if(newX >= 0 && newY >= 0 && newX < seq.length && newY < seq[newX].length
        && seq[newX][newY]) {
        cnt++;
      }
   }       
   return cnt;
}

console.log(neighbors(seq, 0,1))
console.log(neighbors(seq, 1,0))
console.log(neighbors(seq, 2,2))
```